# What is the policy around critique questions and how do we clarify it?

Tags: discussion, faq-contents

Problems:

- The FAQ does not address whether critique requests are appropriate yet this is clearly something users are not clear on
- Meta has a lot of discussion around critique policy but no decisions
- A person just tried to ask what other sites exist for critique which seems totally valid and yet was closed:  https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/2611/mobile-app-ui-feedback-site

Question:
 
**What needs to happen for the FAQ to be updated on this point?**  Yes meta is to discuss the issues but important items need to converge to action at some point.

Comment: To answer your second question: A draft of the section of the FAQ that we can edit is in [this answer](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/108/what-should-our-faq-contain/110#110). If you have specific suggestions, please comment or edit the answer.

Comment: @Patrick - If I want to propose a way to handle critique requests in general should I add an answer to that question (don't think I cane edit)?  The gist is I think we should allow brief reviews that offer feedback that can be generalized into useful community information.

Comment: Yes, adding an answer to the question would be helpful too. If you'd like to propose a new draft of the FAQ, it would probably be most effective to put the draft in a new question and ask, "Can we change the FAQ to this?"

Comment: Regarding your third bullet point - `just tried to ask`? Did you notice the date on that question? It's 10 months old.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My current theory is that the question should be **self contained**. We should be able to fully understand the question without clicking a link or downloading an app. My hope is that if we enforce that rule, askers will be forced to put some thought into their questions and keep the scope reasonably narrow.