# Are "please comment on my site" questions valid

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the policy around critique questions and how do we clarify it?](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/488/what-is-the-policy-around-critique-questions-and-how-do-we-clarify-it)

I did ask one a little while ago, but that related to a specific question I had been asked. I have another site, and, because of the responses from that one, I realise I don't have a particularly good eye, and would like insight. This is a personal one, so I cannot justify a formal assessment.

However, I don't want to cause trouble by asking for site assessments - it seems a little like the homework questions on SO. So would it be acceptable? What would the guidelines be?

And it would only be for comments on the UX, not for a full assessment of "does the site work".